# asp.net mvc login user using formsauthentication cookieless

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I'm writing a custom membership provider that uses LINQ to manage my users. I'm also creating my own tables to manage a user. How would I login a user using the FormsAuthentication object if I want auth to be cookieless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to avoid cookieless session persistence at all costs. It means persistence via the URL which is very vulnerable to session hijacking. Take a look at the example in [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 3: Broken authentication and session management](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-3.html).

Are you really confident you have clients authenticating who don't support cookies and you willing to compromise security for these individuals?

Answer (score 1):

In regular asp.net IIS manages that for you by inserting the session id in the URL.

By the way this is not the safest approach, as the session can be stolen.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Comment: Also, using session would be problematic if you're using load balancing servers.